# Calcular fecha a partir de dia del año

Tags: c#, asp.net, net, busqueda-rango-de-fechas, optimizar

Quiero obtener el calculo de una fecha a partir del dia del año (suponiendo dia 100).

Si aporta al código también tengo el dato como parámetro del número de semana y día de la semana (siendo 0 para domingo por ejemplo).
Ingreso por teclado el año (y realizo un calculo si es bisiesto o no). Con eso no hay problema.

Mi idea es si hay alguna manera de **optimizar el siguiente código**:

```
private static DateTime CalcularDiaDeEntrega(int diaDelAnio, int anio)
    {
        if (diaDelAnio < 32)
            return new DateTime(anio, 1, diaDelAnio);
        else if (diaDelAnio >= 32 && diaDelAnio <= 59)
        {
            return new DateTime(anio, 2, diaDelAnio - 31);
        }
        else if (diaDelAnio >= 60 && diaDelAnio <= 90)
        {
            return new DateTime(anio, 3, diaDelAnio - 59);
        }
        else if (diaDelAnio >= 91 && diaDelAnio <= 120)
        {
            return new DateTime(anio, 4, diaDelAnio - 90);
        }
        else if (diaDelAnio >= 121 && diaDelAnio <= 151)
        {
            return new DateTime(anio, 5, diaDelAnio - 120);
        }
        else if (diaDelAnio >= 152 && diaDelAnio <= 181)
        {
            return new DateTime(anio, 6, diaDelAnio - 151);
        }
        else if (diaDelAnio >= 182 && diaDelAnio <= 212)
        {
            return new DateTime(anio, 7, diaDelAnio - 181);
        }
        else if (diaDelAnio >= 213 && diaDelAnio <= 243)
        {
            return new DateTime(anio, 8, diaDelAnio - 212);
        }
        else if (diaDelAnio >= 244 && diaDelAnio <= 273)
        {
            return new DateTime(anio, 9, diaDelAnio - 243);
        }
        else if (diaDelAnio >= 274 && diaDelAnio <= 304)
        {
            return new DateTime(anio, 10, diaDelAnio - 273);
        }
        else if (diaDelAnio >= 305 && diaDelAnio <= 334)
        {
            return new DateTime(anio, 11, diaDelAnio - 304);
        }
        return new DateTime(anio, 12, diaDelAnio - 334);            
    }
```

Este mismo código (duplicado) pero con otros rangos de fechas aplico para si el caso de que el año sea bisiesto.
Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static DateTime CalcularDiaDeEntrega(int diaDelAnio, int anio)
        => new DateTime(anio,1,1).AddDays(diaDelAnio-1);
```

Tomas el primer día del año y le añades la cantidad de días (menos 1, porque ya estás en el primer día)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me sirvió! Saludos